# TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String) on login when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I deployed a project to Heroku and am currently getting a "TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String)" in my heroku logs when I try and login.

It works fine locally so I am unsure as to what's going wrong.

```
2017-05-22T09:28:53.701881+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-05-22T09:28:53.701785 #4]  INFO -- : [9748b196-6755-447a-a783-
03e1d4636790] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 76ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2017-05-22T09:28:53.624924+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-05-22T09:28:53.624813 #4]  INFO -- : [9748b196-6755-447a-a783-03e1d4636790] Started POST "/login" for 81.154.127.158 at 2017-05-22 09:28:53 +0000
2017-05-22T09:28:53.702530+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-22T09:28:53.702491 #4] FATAL -- : [9748b196-6755-447a-a783-03e1d4636790]   
2017-05-22T09:28:53.702586+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-22T09:28:53.702545 #4] FATAL -- : [9748b196-6755-447a-a783-03e1d4636790] lib/auth.rb:8:in `issue'
2017-05-22T09:28:53.702441+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-22T09:28:53.702368 #4] FATAL -- : [9748b196-6755-447a-a783-03e1d4636790]   
2017-05-22T09:28:53.702489+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-22T09:28:53.702444 #4] FATAL -- : [9748b196-6755-447a-a783-03e1d4636790] TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
2017-05-22T09:28:53.702587+00:00 app[web.1]: [9748b196-6755-447a-a783-03e1d4636790] app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:16:in `login'
```

I think it's saying something is going wrong in either my auth.rb or my auth controller but can't see where.

lib/auth.rb:

```
  def self.issue(payload, expiry_in_minutes=60*24*30)
   payload[:exp] = expiry_in_minutes.minutes.from_now.to_i
   JWT.encode(payload, auth_secret, ALGORITHM)
  end
```

authentications_controller.rb:

```
def login
 user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
 if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
   token = Auth.issue({ id: user.id })
   render json: { token: token, user: UserSerializer.new(user) }, status: :ok
 else
   render json: { errors: ["Invalid login credentials."] }, status: 401
 end
end
```

You can have a look at the full repo [HERE](https://github.com/tjallen27/rails-blog-api) if needed.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: I dont think, `payload[:exp] = expiry_in_minutes.minutes.from_now.to_i` this line will work, this may throw you an other error saying `undefined method `minutes' for Fixnum`

Comment: shouldn't you be setting `data` in the payload ?, perhaps instead of `id: user.id` what you need is `data: user.id`. I'm not sure about that, I've never used JWT gem before.

Comment: I've had it written exactly like this before and it's worked absolutely fine, so i'm unsure as to why this time it's not working. It works when I run it on localhost, it's only after I deployed it to Heroku that it has this error. I read other posts that suggested it could be to do with the gem file, but i've updated that as well and still not working.

Comment: Is any of this set in environment variables? `payload`, `auth_secret` or `ALGORITHM`?

Comment: @Iceman auth_secret was missing! All fixed now. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out (from the comments), that there was a missing environment variable. Setting those in heroku is done like this from the terminal/console.

```
heroku config:set MY_VARIABLE=myvalue
```

Getting the list of environment variables is equally enjoyable with

```
heroku config
# MY_VARIABLE:   myvalue
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars